# Oracle: LIKE where any part of one string matches any part of another string

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using PL/SQL v7.1

I am trying to find all address records where the country name has been entered in one of the address line fields, and also the country field.
The problem is that the country details have not been entered consistently eg.

```
addr4       addr5            country
----------  ----------       ---------------
JERSEY                       UK(JERSEY)
IRELAND                      REPUBLIC OFIRELAND
DOUGLAS      ISLE OF MAN     UK(ISLE OF MAN)
```

So, I need to find the records where ANY PART of the Country field is also found in either addr4 or addr5.

I started with this

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_addresses          
WHERE addr4||addr5 LIKE '%'||country||'%'
```

I know this doesn't work because it will, taking the 1st record as an example, check if 'UK(JERESEY)' is found in addr4||addr5 and ,so, no match will be found. But how do I make it check if 'JERSEY' is found in addr4||addr5

Comment: "*I am using PL/SQL v7.1*": there is no PL/SQL in your example (only plain SQL). And Oracle v7 has been non-existing for over 20 years now. So what exactly are you using?

Comment: Maybe, I got that wrong. I just went into the Help/About tab and that's what it said.

Comment: That is the version information of your SQL tool, not the version information of the Oracle database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_addresses
WHERE (addr4 is not null and country like '%'||addr4||'%')
or (addr5 is not null  and country like '%'||addr5||'%')
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ded6/8/0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know so much about plsql 
but I think your query is backwards, try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_addresses 
WHERE country LIKE '%'||addr4||'%' 
   or country LIKE '%'||addr5||'%'
```

Comment: Indeed it was backwards. Thank you.