# select where one column part of another

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, sql-like

I want to select all rows from my table where value of one column begins with value of another column.

```
Table
column_a         column_b

abc              abcdef
pqr              rstrv
xyz              xyzabc
uvw              abcdef
```

I want to get

```
pqr              rstrv
uvw              abcdef
```

I'm using the query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_b NOT LIKE column_a + '%'
```

I'm getting the error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ '%' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

I've tried solutions from these questions
[Compare Columns Where One is Similar to Part of Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700550/compare-columns-where-one-is-similar-to-part-of-another)

[Oracle: LIKE where any part of one string matches amy part of another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079431/oracle-like-where-any-part-of-one-string-matches-amy-part-of-another-string)

[SQL search column where one item in column is substring of another item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628400/sql-search-column-where-one-item-in-column-is-substring-of-another-item)

[SQL search column where one item in column is substring of another item Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747107/sql-search-column-where-one-item-in-column-is-substring-of-another-item-update). But still resulting in error or wrong results

My mysql version is Server version: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu).
I'm using phpMyAdmin to execute queries.

Comment: Why do you want these two rows and not `abc` + `xyz`? Your query suggests that you want the opposite, all rows where the second column not starts with the first column.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because the rows with column_a values abc, xyz, column_b starts with same value, ie, value of column_a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but MySQL doesn't support the `+` operator for string concatination, only for mathematical addition. Instead, just use the [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_b NOT LIKE CONCAT(column_a, '%')
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you should use `CONCAT()` instead of `+`:

```
select *
from TableName
where column_b not like CONCAT(column_a,'%')
```

In SQL Server:

```
select *
from TableName
where column_b not like column_a+'%'
```

Comment: This is a better explanation to my problem. I'm sorry I couldn't accept this answer. Really appreciate the time you took.

Comment: Why can't some dbms products be ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to concatenation? It's pretty simple to add the ANSI SQL || concatenation to the SQL grammar...

Comment: This is a better answer and was given before the accepted answer. I wonder why OP didn't accept this one.

Comment: @RoshanJossy: No problem, mate. Glad I could help

Comment: @SouravA: Thanks for the comment. Since I took a little more time to add the explanation regarding the difference between these 2 RDBMSs, Mureinik posted his answer first (in a difference of 1 min). That is not a problem. After all, we are here to help each other, right? Not for the sake of reputation points :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_b NOT LIKE CONCAT(column_a,'%')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_b LIKE CONCAT('%', column_a, '%')
```